# Launchy won't startup correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, launchy

I recently made the switch to Ubuntu 10.04, and I've enjoyed it for the most part.  However, I'm having trouble getting Launchy to run on startup.  I sent to System > Preferences > Startup Applications and added the command found in the shortcut (launchy %u) to a new startup app.  It seems to work; the little launch icon is in the taskbar next to the date. But when I hit alt+space (The shortcut I setup to start the Launchy input box), a blank box appears instead of the Launchy input box.  If I kill off the startup application and run Launchy from Applications > Accessories, then it works perfectly fine.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?  This has worked with other startup apps, so why is Launchy different?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Gnome as your desktop, then try using Gnome-Do instead of Launchy.

Answer (score 0):

On my Kubuntu 10.4 just typing

```
launchy
```

runs Launchy correctly. %u is a KDE menu placeholder (maybe Gnome too, I'm not sure), it's not a Launchy command line parameter.

I hope this helps.